# SQL (Postgres): query array Column which must be a subset of an array

Tags: postgresql, query, array

I have a table "article" and for each entry there are some "tags" stored (array column)

```
name   |   tags

test1  | {t1,t3}
test2  | {t2,t3}
test3  | {t3}
test4  | {t1,t5} 
test5  | {t1,t3}
test6  | {t2,t3}
```

I can query for tags which passed as an array:

`SELECT name, tags FROM article WHERE tags && array['t1','t3','t10']::_varchar`

This is working but I actually want to achieve that just entries will be returned when all tags of the entry are in the passed array. (not just 1)

[image]

Comment: Please always start with table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and Postgres version. Most importantly: data type of `tags`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the contains operator `<@` to check if the tags array contains all elements of the "other" array

```
SELECT name, tags 
FROM article 
WHERE tags <@ array['t1','t3','t10']::varchar[]
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8d3cac22950f917993b883c9ecb8f4d4)

Comment: `operator does not exist: json <@ character varying[]`. Either two arrays or two JSONB values.

Comment: @Akina: but tags is an array column, not a JSON column. `{t1,t3}` is the default string representation for an array. If that was a JSON column it would be `["t1","t3"]`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your answer. in your "online example" it will return only "test6". What I want to achieve is: in your example it should return test1, test5 and test6. sorry for the missunderstanding. the entries don't have to have all tags but all tags of the entry must exist in the array['t1','t3','t10'];

Comment: @user1117605: sounds like you only want `where tags <@ ...` - But why not `test3` then?  `{t3}` is also full contained in `{t1,t3,t10}`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name works like a charm thanks (missed the test3)

Comment: so the solution which fits for me is: `SELECT name, tags FROM article WHERE tags <@ array['t1','t3','t10'];
`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WHERE tags <@ '["t1","t3","t10"]'::JSONB; 
-- or
SELECT * FROM test WHERE tags <@ TO_JSONB(ARRAY['t1','t3','t10'])
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=55ff28e62e884047187c9e9f275934f4

`tags` must be the column of JSONB datatype. If not then cast it to JSONB.